# How can I "Fire and forget" certain requests, such as DELETE or PUT or even some POST, with RestKit .20?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, restkit

How can I "Fire and forget" certain requests, such as DELETE or PUT or even some POST, with RK?

I've been googling and have found a solution, but I have to believe there is an easier way that I'm missing. This is what I have:
Model: Room

**Room GET request:** I set up RKObjectMapping, RKResponseDescriptor, route(responds to 200) <--- works perfectly

**Room DELETE request**:  I set up RKObjectMapping, RKResponseDescriptor, route(responds to 204) <--- works perfectly

**My question is: Is there an easier way to do this?** 
Maybe I'm being lazy, but setting up  RKObjectMapping, RKResponseDescriptor for every action seems like a lot of extra work if I don't plan on doing anything with the response. (Note: even error handling isn't necessary.)

I'm relatively new to restkit, sorry if I'm missing something obvious. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks for indulging my laziness :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the response (or even the result status) then you don't need to define response descriptors. Technically RestKit will raise an error result because no response descriptors could be found but that doesn't matter to you.

If you aren't using the get/put/post object methods then an alternative would be to define a single mapping to an NSDictionary. The mapping could have a single key (or it may work with no keys). Then, for any request where you don't care about the response you can provide a valid mapping which is basically a no-op.

Another alternative is to write a single method which takes a Class and returns an empty response descriptor. You'll still have some configuration calls but much less code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's what I did originally, but noticed a slight hang(UI became briefly unresponsive) because of it. This was resolved when I added the descriptor, but it also means a lot more code. I was hopping there was some way to send the request without triggering an error either. Thanks